# Can we use android scripting environment for functional test automation?

Tags: android, automation, ase

I want to automate some of my functional test cases on android , can I use Android scripting environment and use Python / Perl to automate my functional test cases?

Thanks

AD

Comment: Please define what you mean by "functional test cases" for your project.

Comment: CommonsWare - "functional test cases" are most likely referring to test case for checking functionality of an application a.k.a black box testing. I too would like to know if there are tools for automating black box test cases for Android.